# JS: Generating onclick functions dynamically via for...in loop only taking last property in object

Tags: javascript

I've read posts that detail how to use `onclick = function(){};` to dynamically generate onclick events.

However, I cannot figure out how to successfully pass arguments to a function *within* this anonymous onclick function.

http://jsfiddle.net/2f9qq931/

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>

function subFunction(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

function myFunction() {

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var list = {
        "one": "cat",
        "two": "dog",
        "three": "fish"
    };

    for (item in list) {
        var clickable = document.createElement("div");
            clickable.innerHTML = list[item];
            clickable.onclick = function() {
                subFunction(item);
            }
        container.appendChild(clickable);
    }
}

myFunction();

</script>
```

This should give me

```
<div>cat</div>
<div>dog</div>
<div>fish</div>
```

And upon clicking each div, the console will log `one` `two` and `three`

...but the console is only logging `three`. How do I get `subFunction` to correctly log the object properties?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: All your handlers are sharing the same `item`variable, which by the time they are called have the last value. See the linked question and http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/2f9qq931/2/ which creates a separate variable for each handler

Comment: Thanks for your help; I'll mark this as answered when I figure how to do that...

Comment: I think a better description of the issue is contained in this article: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/ - the section on closures will explain the issues.  You'll need an immediate function like this: for (item in list) {
            (function(item){
                var clickable = document.createElement("div");
                clickable.innerHTML = list[item];
                clickable.onclick = function() {
                    subFunction(item);
                }
                container.appendChild(clickable);
            })(item);
        }